# Cannot get system to boot upp with new cloned disks

Tags: boot, ssd, raid, sata, cloning

Just tried to upgrade my disks from mechanical to SSD type drives on my ASUS M4A785-M motherboard (non-UEFI). Thought I had prepared thoroughly and it seemed that the process was not too difficult for someone of my lesser experience in Linux.
I previously had a hardware RAID1 set of SATA drives and I wanted to replace it with a RAID 1 SSD. Looked at the process and I came to the conclusion that hardware RAID was going to be the easiest way to go.
Formatted  and set up Raid1 on the SSD's, went through the Clonezilla process and it said everything was successful.
Booted my system with the old drives and with the new ones still installed the system started to complain about duplicates so I unattached my new SSDs just to make sure I could boot with the old drives and it did successfully.
Unattached my old drives and attached the new SSDs and it seemed to start booting quite nicely. When it got to the step where it was trying to start the device with /boot, it timed out and failed.
Did some research, checked FSTAB, UUIDs, etc... through the terminal interface you get access to on the failure and it looked right to me, the new stuff was in there and it matched but I am somewhat new to Linux still.
I have difficulty pasting the results of the displays as I cannot boot up far enough to copy and paste the outputs of my FSTAB, blkid, device by UUID (and by ID) and other displays. I can ls the drive but of course /boot shows nothing since it can't be mounted.
At a loss right now for my next step. I recognize if someone is going to help me, they are going to want some output and I will need to switch between the drives a few times so responses will be slow. Not sure, and someone can confirm, I think I can probably pipe the output of these displays to a text file if need be even in that degraded mode....right?
Anyway, any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not know RAID, but this should have all the info required. You may want to run two reports and do your own compare to see what is different.

Comment: Good idea, I will do so, thanks. I am pretty convinced this is probably not a RAID issue (since my old SATA drive were also RAID with no issues) but is something else (although I am not 100% sure).

Comment: Oops, forgot link to Boot-Repair. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please attach link to the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: So, I compared the working (old system) to the new system for the commands cat /etc/fstab and lsblk -o and they are identical except for the name of the devices.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't done....I then booted the new system and it seems the system is trying to start the drive with the old name not the new name. Since both of these configuration files are identical except for the name of the drives, where is that I can change the name of the drive it needs to work with to start /boot. Once I find out where it is, I can correct the name (hopefully that easy) and then everything should be ok. Anybody??

Comment: Post link to Boot-Repair summary report. Ubuntu/grub boots by UUID. And UEFI boots from GUID of ESP partition. If new GUID, you may need new UEFI entry. If UUID is same it should boot?

Comment: UUID is the same and this motherboard does not support UEFI.

Comment: I was in error, tired. Fstab has wrong info. It has the old drive name still listed for ext2. I will fix it up and see if that resolved the issue.

Comment: Resolved. Thanks  ordered for all your assistance. Edited fstab with correct name and I am back in business.

Comment: Good. You can add your own solution as an answer that may help others.

Answer (score 0):

It was that easy. Edited fstab to the names of the drives and the boot worked.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would please explain the steps required to apply your solution.